# Rename a column in a view when sorting in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a field named `Region`, and i want to display it as `Région`, because I am a French user. But, it is using the sort function of `Paginator` as:

```
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('region');?></th>
```

How can I do it? I tried:

```
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('region','région');?></th>
```

but it doesn't work. I'm using `cakephp 1.3` to perform my work (I am constrained to do with it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use title in first parameter and Model.fieldName in another parameter
Like

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Title Name', 'Model.fieldname');?></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ModelName.region','région');?></th>
```

Hopefully that'll work.

Comment: Thanks, but I have just reverse the parameter order. And it works, like i reply toGirish above.